# Task time and GC time calculation in Spark UI in Executor section

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to understand about  task time and GC time in executor section in Spark Databricks.
For all task it took around 20 mins actual time to complete execution of all tasks. But when I see  it shows in **UI** as 4.7 hr. I want to understand how Gc time and task time is calculated here because in reality it completed in lot more lesser time than what displayed.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Tasks run in parallel, the task time can be way higher than the actual time that passed.

As you can see there are 12 active tasks in this screenshot, running in parallel.

Comment: Are you saying it's like just the predicted time because it's always way higher than actual time which it took to complete

Comment: No, if you have only one core, then the task time should be exactly the same as the actual time.

Comment: ohh ok so actual time should be equal to total_time_displayed/total_no_of_cores ?

Comment: Roughly, yes. This would only be the case if all cores are always working at a 100% which is highly unlikely. So it's rather **actual_time >= total_time_displayed/total_no_of_cores** because there will be idle times.